# Using mPDF to create a PDF from a HTML form

Tags: forms, fpdf, html-encode, mpdf

I want to use mpdf to create my PDF-files because I use norwegian letters such as ÆØÅ. The information on the PDF-file would mostly consist of text written by the user in a HTML form. But, I have some problems.

When using this code:

```
$mpdf->WriteHTML('Text with ÆØÅ');
```

The PDF will show the special characters.

But when using this:

```
<?php
include('mpdf/mpdf.php');

$name = 'Name - <b>' . $_POST['name'] . '</b>';

$mpdf = new mPDF();

$mpdf->WriteHTML($name);

$mpdf->Output();
exit;

?>
```

The special characters will not show.

The HTML form looks like this:

```
<form action="hidden.php" method="POST">
    <p>Name:</p>
    <input type="text" name="name">

   <input type="submit" value="Send"><input type="reset" value="Clear">
</form>
```

Why won't the special characters show with this method? And which method should I use?

Comment: It's probably some encoding issue. Try **$mpdf->WriteHTML(utf8_encode($name));** for a start. Is your website encoded UTF8 or Latin1? You should get the POST-data in the same encoding and maybe you need another one for mpdf.

Comment: Using $mpdf->WriteHTML(utf8_encode($name)); did not solve it.

Comment: The documentation says it supports UTF8 encoded HTML, so this seems to not be the problem. echoing $name back on the webpage yields the desired result, I guess?

Comment: When echoing the characters do NOT show.

Comment: So it's not an issue with mpdf but with your site in general. I've just checked on my site where I have a little chat installed and your charracters work fine. The only thing I'm doing there is encoding the whole website in utf8 and using htmspecialchars() on the POST data to prevent malicious content but this should have no effect here. Did you set an encoding?

Comment: I added <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" /> to the html-file with the form. It now shows Ã¦Ã¸Ã¥

Comment: That's at least something. Does it show the same in the PDF now?

Comment: Yes, it does show with Ã¦Ã¸Ã¥.

Comment: I had it with utf8, and when i removed it. And added header("Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8");
 to the php-file. It worked! And it is still working when I removed the header.

Comment: Okay, makes sense to me because utf8_encode() converts from latin to utf. If it's already utf8 it goes wrong obviously... You removed the header? So it's the same as before and it's working?

Comment: Can this have something to do with that I created the file in Cpanel file manager, and now downloaded and edited the file in notepad++? I removed the header in the PHP-file, not the HTML one. But I removed it from the HTML as well now. And it is still working.

Comment: Possibly so, if they save the file in different encodings. However, I would suggest to always use an encoding in the header anyways. I would also suggest to either remove or reformulate/move your question as it is in no way related to mpdf.

Comment: I've added the htmlspecialchars() as well to be safe :). Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hey, @inVader, you helped Anders out with this,  How about just adding all this to an answer so he can select it as correct?

Comment: Maybe you should also tag this with 'html-encoding' as it's not really an mpdf issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since echoing the POST-data back onto the website does not show the characters as well, this clearly isn't an issue with mpdf. When using content including non-Ascii characters, special care about the websites character encoding has to be taken.

From the mpdf-documentation it can be seen that it supports UTF-8 encoding, so you might want to use that for your data. POST-data is received in the same encoding that is used by the website. So if the website is in latin-1, you will need to call **utf8_encode()** to convert the POST-data to unicode. If the website already uses UTF-8 you should be just fine.

If you don't set a specific encoding in the website header (which you should always to avoid this kind of trouble), encoding might depend on several factors such as the operating system and configuration on the server or the encoding of the original php sourcefile which, as it turns out, is influenced by your own OS configuration and choice of editor.